# How do i write a jQuery input string so that it works with Django query string

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-views

Am working on a name search app but having a challenge getting it to work with Django query string, the challenge which i observed comes from my JavaScript input type with ${input} string when added to Django query string eg. "address/get-name/?search=${input}" doesn't return the query object or the payload data, instead it return an empty list, but when i make search through the browser it return all search query data eg  "address/get-name/?search=smith", Now how do i get input through my scripts without having to use the java scripts query input type ${input} with django so let i get a query string like this "address/get-name/?search=james" ? Here is my script, Am a novice in JavaScript

```
<script>
    new Autocomplete('#autocomplete',{

         search : input => {
             console.log(input)
             const url = "/address/get-names/?search=${input}"
             return new Promise(resolve => {
                
                 fetch(url)
                 .then( (response) => response.json())
                 .then( data => {
                    console.log(data.playload)
                     resolve(data.playload)
                     
                })
             })
         },
         renderResult : (result, props) =>{
             console.log(props)
             let group =  ''
             if (result.index % 3 == 0 ){
                 group = '<li class="group">Group</li>'
             }
             return '${group}<li ${props}><div class="wiki title">${result.name}</div></li>'
            
         }
        
     })

     
</script>
```

my view.py

```
def get_names(request):
    search = request.GET.get('search')
    payload = []
    if search:
        objs = Names.objects.filter(name__startswith=search)
        for obj in objs:
            payload.append({
            'name' : obj.name
            })
            
    return JsonResponse({
        '200': True,
        'playload': payload  
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your javascript syntax, it's

```
const url = `/address/get-names/?search=${input}`
```

instead of

```
const url = "/address/get-names/?search=${input}"
```